# Getting a meaningful error message from async_status loop when retries exceeded

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible 1.7, I am executing multiple asynchronous tasks in a loop, and checking on their status with async_status with a 30-second timeout:

```
- name: Some long-running task
  shell: "./some_task {{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ list_of_params }}"
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  register: my_task

- name: Check async tasks for completion
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: my_task_results
  until: my_task_results.finished
  retries: 30
  delay: 1
  loop: "{{ my_task.results }}"
```

This works well, and the async_status task fails if any of the shell commands return non-zero return-code, or if "my_task_results.finished" is not true within 30 seconds.

Unfortunately, the error message is not helpful when the "until" condition is not met in time. The returned values include:

- changed: false
- msg: "All items completed"
- results: [ array of results from shell task above ]
- changed: false
- failed: true
- finished: 0

Particularly, the "All items completed" message is misleading.

Is there a way to produce a meaningful error message in this case? I can add a "failed_when" option, with an additional "Fail" task to check condition (finished == 0) to display a custom error message (Something to the effect of "Some long-running task did not complete in time"), but this seems inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will be fine in this case.

Please look to Official Ansible Docs: 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id10

Here you can find your method:

```
- name: Fail if return code is not 0
  fail:
    msg: "The command ({{ item.cmd }}) did not have a 0 return code"
  when: item.rc != 0
  loop: "{{ echo.results }}"
```

Sometimes when I need more beauty - more descriptive output I'm using template/file, then with a registered variable in the task, you can customize your output.

```
For example: 
- name:
  template:
... 

- shell: cat <template_location>.yml
  register: stack_test

- debug:
    msg: "{{ stack_test.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work with async tasks.
The only vars returned for an async task are 'ansible_job_id', 'changed', 'failed', 'finished', 'item', 'results_file', and 'started'.

Only after the task completes do the other vars become visible.

I can certainly report that the task did not complete in time, but I can't determine any other information about the task, such as command, stdout, stderr, etc. If only there were some way to at least get the cmd from an async task ...

Comment: @FSchwartz it seem that async_status can poll and populate a structure containing the stdout_lines.  However, I can't figure out how to get an async_status task to loop on its own registered variable and output that